Is the X-Frame-Options header recommended when the server response is not in HTML format?
I'm currently auditing an API and all the endpoints are sending me a response in JSON format.
I saw on the OWASP website that only the CSP, Permissions-Policy and Referrer-Policy headers are not necessary when the server response is not in HTML format.

My question is: Why isn't the X-Frame-Options header included?
This header prevents a web page from being iframised, and therefore potentially vulnerable to a clickjacking attack.
In the case of response formats other than HTML, I don't see the point of having this header.

Please do no include images of text. I don't see the point of including a screenshot of a text-heavy page, especially without the (required) link back to the original.

The document that you have provided a screenshot of, https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#security-headers, has a table above your screenshot with the recommended headers for all API responses, including both X-Frame-Options and Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors. The table you have shown lists the additional headers that should be included if the API may return html.
